# NSArrayController is sometimes not letting me set `selectedObjects`

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have subclassed `NSArrayController` to prove to myself that something's wrong

In my subclass, I overrode `-setSelectedObjects`:

```
-(BOOL)setSelectedObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    NSArray *previousSelected = [[self selectedObjects] copy];
    selectionChanged = [super setSelectedObjects:objects];
    NSArray *afterSelected = [self selectedObjects];
    //Below is a desperate attempt to get my array to set
    if( [previousSelected isEqualToArray:afterSelected] )
    {
       [super removeSelectedObjects:previousSelected];
       [super addSelectedObjects:objects];
    }
    return selectionChanged;
}
```

**Below is my LLDB output**

Here you can see that my `NSArrayController` contains two `ImageGraphics` in `arrangedObjects`

```
(lldb) po [self arrangedObjects] <_NSControllerArrayProxy
0x6080000146a0>( <ImageGraphic: 0x618000124d80> <{226, 274}> <{318,
178}>, <ImageGraphic: 0x618000124880> <{337, 343}> <{438, 246}> )
```

Here you can see that before I call `[super setSelectedObjects:]` my `selectedObjects` array has one `ImageGraphic`:

```
(lldb) po [self selectedObjects] <__NSArrayI 0x61800003b1e0>(
<ImageGraphic: 0x618000124d80> <{226, 274}> <{318, 178}> )
```

Here you can see my `objects` array, the array that I want to **set** as my `selectedObjects`.  Note the `ImageGraphic here is the other object that is not currently in`selectedObjects`:

```
(lldb) po objects
<__NSArrayI 0x60800063ce40>(
<ImageGraphic: 0x618000124880> <{337, 343}> <{438, 246}>
)
```

Now even though we can clearly see that `objects` contains a different object that `selectedObjects` currently contains, `-setSelectedObjects` does nothing.

Here is the value of `previousSelected` and `selectedObjects` **after** I called `[super setSelectedObjects]`

```
(lldb) po previousSelected
<__NSArrayI 0x61800003b1e0>(
<ImageGraphic: 0x618000124d80> <{226, 274}> <{318, 178}>
)

(lldb) po [self selectedObjects]
<__NSArrayI 0x61800003b1e0>(
<ImageGraphic: 0x618000124d80> <{226, 274}> <{318, 178}>
)
```

Nothing changed.

You can also see I made a desperate attempt to remove and add the `selectedObjects`, however even `[super removeSelectedObjects:previousSelected]` doesn't affect `selectedObjects`.

It appears that I am in some kind of a state where `selectedObjects` cannot be modified.  Which doesn't make sense because every set method is returning `YES`, implying to me that it's working.

I have also tried overriding `-removeSelectedObjects`, `-addSelectedObjects` to see if they are being executed without my knowledge.  But that doesn't appear to be the case

**Is there any reason at all why `NSArrayController` cannot be modified at a specific time?**

***NOTE that this actually works most of the time***

Comment: Have you verified this: `Attempting to change the selection may cause a commitEditing message which fails, thus denying the selection change.` - from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/setSelectedObjects:)

Comment: Yes, `commitEditing` returns `YES`

Comment: Did you bind (to) selectedIndexes or selectedObjects?

Comment: It's possible, I can check tomorrow-- if that was the case, what could be happening? wouldn't `setSelectedObjects` be called through bindings?

Comment: Maybe the selection is changed and then restored because the selection change triggers a piece of code somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured this one out, 
`NSGraphicsArrayController` has two key properties here:
`arrangedObjects` and `selectedObjects`

`selectedObjects` array should only contain objects that exist in `arrangedObjects`

So we were adding objects to `arrangedObjects`, and then `selectedObjects`.
And adding to the selection was failing only with specific objects

Turns out those specific objects were being added to `arrangedObjects` through `-insertObjects:atIndex:`, whereas the objects that were successfully being added to the selection were being added through `-addObjects`

There must have been something going wrong with our indexes in `arrangedObjects` that was confusing `selectedObjects`

So the solution was to just use `-addObjects` everywhere, and `selectedObjects` always updated as we expect it to